# while loop preg_match

Tags: php, loops, preg-match

I want to loop:

```
$embed = array();
preg_match('@&lt;embed.*?&lt;/embed&gt;@s', $text, $embed);
```

How do I loop the $embed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you make a loop? Well, there are several ways...

```
#1...
foreach ($embed as $e) {
    #do stuff with $e as the current item
}

#2...
$len = count($embed);
for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
    #do stuff with $embed[$i] as the current item
}
#or, with a while loop
#3...
while ($len--) {
    #do stuff with $embed[$i] as the current item
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach( $embed as $match ){}
```

Or is this a trick question?

Comment: Is this a trick answer? (Shouldn't it be `foreach($embed as $match)...`?) :-)

Comment: I was so confused by the question that i forgot how to write PHP =)

Comment: Lol, I was so confused myself. Thought there was some other way to loop from preg_match. Thanks for the anser though. Probably confused you even more :P